# How sorted lambda with two keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, sorting

i'm uses this

```
ThreadList.append([''.join(map(str,[Thread])), date, rrf[5]])

SendThreadList = ''

ThreadList = sorted(ThreadList, key=lambda Entry: Entry[1], reverse=True)
ThreadList = sorted(ThreadList, key=lambda Entry: Entry[2], reverse=True)
```

sorted show only the second sorted, how to do sorted with two entrys in key ??

Comment: sorry for my bad english, i'm brazilian

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `''.join(map(str,[Thread]))`? Applying `map`, I get `''.join([str(Thread)])` which of course is just `str(Thread)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to sort by Entry[1], then Entry[2] then you make the lambda return both as a tuple...:

```
ThreadList = sorted(ThreadList, key=lambda Entry: (Entry[1], Entry[2]), reverse=True)
```

What's sometimes more readable (and potentially slightly quicker) is to make use of the `operator` module and use `key=operator.itemgetter(1, 2)`

Comment: @GeorgeSet. Sorry - I don't understand - could you try re-phrasing please?

Comment: ThreadList = sorted(ThreadList, key=lambda Entry: (Entry[1], Entry[2]), reverse=True)

Comment: @GeorgeSet. What I don't get is "check the Entry[2] is 1" ?

Comment: @GeorgeSet. Yes, but it may be better as a new question with some context about what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

While it is the wrong way to do it, your example will work if you swap the order:

```
ThreadList = sorted(ThreadList, key=lambda Entry: Entry[2], reverse=True)
ThreadList = sorted(ThreadList, key=lambda Entry: Entry[1], reverse=True)
```

Python sorts are stable - if two entries tie on `[1]`, they will keep their order from the first sort.